# jQuery prevent stop() from giving fixed height to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following lines of code:

```
$(".product-list .product").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.product-description').stop().slideDown("slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.product-description').stop().slideUp("slow");
})
```

Now the problem is, when I move fast enough, and then hover the element again, the .product-description get stuck to the height of the old event.

For example:

1. mouseover: element -> animates -> full height: 200px
2. mouseleave: element -> animation stops -> animates -> height: 0 (default height now: 100px)
3. mouseover: element -> animates -> full height: 100px (but should be 200px)

And yes I already tried by getting the normal height - but the problem is, that I use clearfix what jQuery can't really handle.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: +1 for good way of asking question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using it like below,

```
$(".product-list .product").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.product-description').stop(true, true).slideDown("slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.product-description').stop(true, true).slideUp("slow");
})
```

> **.stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )**
>
> **clearQueueA** Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as
>   well. Defaults to false.
>
> **jumpToEndA** Boolean indicating whether to complete the current
>   animation immediately. Defaults to false.

Comment: Thanks - I already found that solution, but I don't like it that way :)

Comment: @Lumio And may I ask why you don't like it? It looks to me like the right way to clear the animation queue

Comment: yes, it would be a solution, but I don't like, how it jumps around.

Comment: @Lumio Try to set up a fiddle where we can take a look.